# What is the better apporach to print a large json data in java 'getOutputStream' or 'getWriter'

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets, service

Scenario is like i need to print very large json data set. This json data is consumed by mobile application's. In Java service application, used as below to print the json.

```
response.getWriter().println(mainjson);
```

getWriter taking too much time to print all the data.

I heard about `getOutputStream` also. Which is faster in case of large json data?
Any help will be appreciated :-)

Comment: The Writer just wraps the OutputStream. Since json is text-based, this is the correct approach. I think the real question is what "getWriter taking too much time" means?

Comment: For really really big data neither. Why not load it in chunks and load each chunk when scrolling down or something

Comment: @f1sh Yes getWriter taking too much time. Is their any approach to decrease the time?

Comment: @AnurajR calling Writer.write will hardly take too much time. What makes you think it's the use of a Writer that takes up the processing time?

Comment: @f1sh While printing such a large json data, feel like its little slow to print whole json. Instead of using getWriter().print, does their any way to print json

Comment: 'Feel like it's a little slow ' is not a measurement. Measure. Don't guess.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you retrieve the data and whether your JSON serializer has a streaming api available.

At the moment you are probably operating in three seperate steps

1. Retrieving all your data
2. Serializing it to JSON string
3. Writing the JSON response.

If you are spending a substantial amount of time on the retrieval and serialization part by itself then you can potentially speed things up by using streams.  However, this requires your data retrieval and json serializer to support streams.

When using streams, instead of doing everything in sequential steps you basically setup a pipeline that allows you to start writing the response a bit earlier.  This is not guaranteed to be faster though, it depends on where your particular bottleneck occurs. If its almost all an issue with the IO to the client then you are not going to see a substantial difference.

**Also**

Something else to look into is check if your are compressing your response to the user. Gzip can have a substantial impact on the size of text data and may reduce your payload sufficiently to make this a non issue.